# what is the meaning of the phrase "nice shot"

Tags: meaning, phrases, vocabulary

In an informal conversation I came to know of this phrase:

> Nice shot, dude.

What does it exactly mean?

Comment: What was the conversation about?

Comment: Could you please provide us with more context? What else was said in the conversation?

Comment: I am afraid I can not. It was part of a small english learning text which was explaining the word "Dude". I am sure I have heard it before but I don't know exactly where and how..

Comment: Can you provide a link, or the name of the coursebook? There's usually some surrounding context, a dialogue, as you can see by the answers posted, shot, has at least two meanings. But the scene could have taken place at a fairground, at a [shooting gallery](https://www.google.it/search?q=shooting+gallery&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieiruriqrJAhUHPQ8KHfMWAU4QsAQINg&biw=1366&bih=677), or maybe they were playing tennis, golf, basketball, ...

Comment: The trouble is that the phrase carries diametrically opposed meanings depending on whether it is said admiringly ("well done, my dear fellow") or sarcastically ("you totally blew it, goofus"). So this is a situation where context is all-important.

Comment: @Mari-LouA sure. here it is http://www.phrasemix.com/examples/dude-where-the-hell-have-you-been

Comment: If you could include that link, then it's clearer why you posed the question. The phrase is taken out of context. The "shot" could be referring to anything: a snapshot, a basketball aim, a rifle shot, or anything that involved attempting to do something; and Sven Yargs observation is very relevant too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice Shot = Good Try/Attempt at something

Comment: Or actual completion of attempt. If one hits a bulls-eye, that's a nice shot.

Answer (score 3):

Nice shot usually means nice picture. In slang if someone takes a good picture of something it is referred to as a nice shot.